# pass tiptap editor data into react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tiptap

I have a form page like this:

```
const PostArticlePage: NextPage = () => {
  const form = useForm<PostArticleInput>();
  const { register, formState, handleSubmit, control } = form;

  return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(postArticle)}>
         <FormControl>
              <FormLabel>
                Add an article title.
              </FormLabel>
              <Input
                id="articleTitle"
                height="48px"
                {...register("title")}
              />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl>
              <FormLabel>
                Add an article description.
              </FormLabel>
              <Input
                id="articleDescription"
                height="48px"
                {...register("description")}
              />
          </FormControl>
)
```

And I'm trying to pass in a tiptap editor as a form input:

```
const EditorArticle = (props: { description: string }) => {
  const editor = useEditor({
    extensions: [
      kit,
      Placeholder.configure({
        placeholder: "Write your article! You're the journalist.",
        showOnlyWhenEditable: false,
      }),
    ],
    content: props.description,
  });
  
  return (
      <EditorContent editor={editor} />
  );
};
```

I've tried passing it into a controller, but can't seem to connect the editor data to the form data:

```
              <FormControl>   
               <Controller 
                render={() => (
                  <EditorArticle description=""/>
                )}
                control={control}
                name="description" // {...register} doesn't work here for some reason
                defaultValue="."
                />
               </FormControl>
```

I tried passing in a prop into the editor and having the content update it, but it is not working. The form doesn't detect anything from the editor. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

I do not know TypeScript, so I have added what you needed in plain JavaScript. Hopefully, you can adjust it to TypeScript.

So what I have done is: in the EditorArticle, I have added the onChange prop (from react hook form). This is where you pass the content from the editor after you update it, and you get this new content from the onUpdate event of the editor.

In the Controller, you needed a way for react hook form to read content from the editor, and you do this by using the field object from react hook form(which contains the onChange method to read content from your editor's onUpdate method, and the value property of the field object stores that content)

```
const EditorArticle = (props: { description: string,onChange }) => {
      const editor = useEditor({
        extensions: [
          kit,
          Placeholder.configure({
            placeholder: "Write your article! You're the journalist.",
            showOnlyWhenEditable: false,
          }),
        ],
        content: props.description,
        onUpdate({ editor }) {
            onChange(editor.getHTML());
        });
      
      return (
          <EditorContent editor={editor} />
      );
};

<FormControl>
 <Controller
    render={({field}) => (
      <EditorArticle 
         description={field.value} 
         onChange={field.onChange}
      />
    )}
    name="description"
    defaultValue="" 
 />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: This works quite well actually but one problem is that every time I type a letter in the editor, it removes focus from the editor and I can't continue to type. Can this be resolved?

Comment: could you create a codesandbox that I can look at?

Comment: Hey, I figured out the problem. I was using useEffect on watch, which was rerendering the component. Removing that resolved the issue.

Comment: Good to know. Glad I was able to help

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly what I needed. Since I wasn't using a FormProvider I had to add  `controller={controller}` as a prop in my `<Controller />` component. (Also have to destructure from useForm, i.e. `const { control } = useForm();` )

Comment: This was helpful, particularly realizing that I had to pass `onUpdate()` as a parameter to `useEditor`. For anyone wondering, more details can be found on this page regarding [Tiptap events](https://tiptap.dev/api/events).

Comment: How do you guys reset the editor? Mine is not working T_T

Comment: @rainz what do you mean by reset editor?

Comment: I'm also having an issue resetting the editor via the `reset` function returned from react-form-hook's `useForm`. I believe it's due to two-way binding not working with `description={field.value}` because `useEditor`'s `content` is only used to set the initial value. Any way to make `field.value` changes be propagated back into the component?